# html-duration-picker does not work correctly inside tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tabs

I am using the html-duration-picker library to display the duration. My problem is that this library is not working within the tabs.
I tested using the library outside tabs and it works, but inside it doesn't work properly, as shown in the image.

Can anyone help me find the solution to this problem?

Thank you

[**Library**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-duration-picker)

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yb5fat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**HTML**

```
    <button (click)="tab1 = 'TT'; tab = 'tabFirst'" rel="TT">OPEN TAB</button>
<input type="text" class="html-duration-picker" data-hide-seconds>
<br>
<div [ngSwitch]="tab1" style="margin-top: 26px; height: 80%;width: 100%; display: flex;align-items: center;">
   <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" *ngSwitchCase="'TT'">
      <div [ngSwitch]="tab" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
         <div style="padding: 32px;" *ngSwitchCase="'tabFirst'">
               <input type="text" class="html-duration-picker" data-hide-seconds>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Image**

[image]